# Django: how to interact with tables from MySQL

Tags: mysql, django, python-2.7

I am trying to write a very simple web application, which could show tables from existing MySQL databases, and authorized users could insert values and delete rows as well. But I am new to Django and do not know how to start the project.

I also tried two tutorials: https://realpython.com/learn/start-django/#django-18   http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/index.html

Basically, I hope Django could show databases'name and tables name automatically. Besides, after clicking one table, users could query the table.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: How about starting to setup the project, and try to connect to the database first? Then you can identify the mapping for your database fields to model fields.  Then you could get specific questions answered when you are stuck ?

Comment: well, I can connect to the databases right now. But I have so many tables, do I need to write model for every table?

Comment: What problems are you having with the tutorials?  In what ways are they not sufficient?

Comment: You need to identify what fields would be editable, etc... and create a reverse mapping. Also, django provides `inspectdb` to autogenerate the models  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/legacy-databases/#auto-generate-the-models

Comment: @trpt4him The tutorials are pretty good and I got some basics for Django.  I will update my problems a little.

Comment: @karthikr thanks, that's pretty helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the manuals carefully. They are the best!
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect tutorial for beginners ..
  [Tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-mysql-or-mariadb-with-your-django-application-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 1):

Using an existing database with Django is no problem. Please have a look at the docs how exactly integrating legacy databases works.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/legacy-databases/

Answer (score -1):

maybe this will help there are a lot of tutorials in the internet

https://realpython.com/learn/start-django/

Comment: Thanks, I already tried that and http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/index.html. Got some basic ideas but not sure how to create table views for Django..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, I appreciate your enthusiasm for answering. Stack is not like other sites and seeks to provide definitive answers rather than discussion. Check the "help" at the top and take the tour to see the ways in which this site is different. Keep trying - we were all new once.